# Navigation bar Title becomes green

Tags: ios, objective-c, menu, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a menu, set with [REfrostedViewController](https://github.com/romaonthego/REFrostedViewController), and everytime I switch between the different view controllers from my menu, the title of my navigation bar becomes greenish.

[Here is an album of the issue happening.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiLpy.jpg)

I use push segues with Interface Builder to push the different view controllers from the menu.

I tried removing all customization (color, font, etc), but it still happens, and not only on the simulator.

This is how I push the views from my menu:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
NavigationViewController *navigationController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"contentController"];

if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0)
{
    HomeViewController *home = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Home"];
    navigationController.viewControllers = @[home];
}
else if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 1)
{
    ProfileViewController *profile = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Profile"];
    navigationController.viewControllers = @[profile];
}
else if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 2)
{
    SortFriendsViewController *sortFriends = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SortFriends"];
    navigationController.viewControllers = @[sortFriends];
}
else if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 3)
{
    InviteViewController *invite = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Invite"];
    navigationController.viewControllers = @[invite];
}
```

Do I need to empty the navigation stack when loading another view controller ? Is there anything I can do ?

If you need more information just ask.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what you want to achieve and can't figure out a lot from your code, but I think the problem is that you change somewhere navigation controller style. BTW why don't you use `-pushViewController:animated` ?

Comment: I'm trying to get rid of that green style the title gets when moving from a view controller to another via the menu.

I'll try to use `pushViewController:animated` instead, I was not using it since it was not the way the author of REfrostedViewController did it. Thanks !

EDIT: It does the same thing with pushViewController:animated, I'll replace every push I did with it since it's easier to understand.